# Can't add a new field of type entity reference!

Tags: 7, entities

Other field types can be added, but only a field of type "Entity Reference" can't be added.

I am getting a status message "Die Einstellungen wurden gespeichert."(Configuration has been saved), but it should redirect me to the manage field of the content type in which I am adding the content type.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It was my browser's cache.

On clearing my browser cache I was able to see the Entity Reference field as well.